# Beautiful premade HTPC which outputs the audio through the HDMI port

Tags: audio, hdmi, htpc

I'm searching for a decent HTPC which outputs the 5.1-audio through the HDMI port. It have to be a pre-made system, not something self-made. And it has to be "beautiful" (e.g. not a big, clunky box)

Do you have some recommendations? I looked at the Dell Studio Hybrid, and found that it would work if one downloads some other drivers than what comes preinstalled. But this guide said that it had to have an ATI graphic card, and the ones for sale now have some "Intel integrated" stuff.. Anyone have experience with this?

Or do you have some other suggestions? This will be a christmas gift, so I hope to get answers before christmas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found the [Dell Zine HD](http://blogs.amd.com/home/2009/11/12/the-dell-inspiron-zinohd/).. Looks like it's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider, which may be more flexible than a HTPC (other than the lack of an optical drive), is a netbook that has an HDMI port and can provide 1080p output.